# Textures to Object in Unity / Vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures, vuforia

I'm trying to do some Augmented Reality in Unity using the Vuforia plugin. I've managed to get everything working (I'm using a 3d model of a car), only the position of the car relative to the marker is wrong when I come to preview it (click the 'Play button at the top and watch through the computer's camera - is 'preview' the right name for this?).

It should be sitting on the the marker in the center, but instead it's floating above the marker and off to the side by quite a bit. The positioning is definitely right in the program itself, so I'm not sure why this isn't reflected in the preview.

Also: at the moment the car is simply an untextured grey object. I realise the textures are included in a subfolder, however I can't drag the entire car's folder (including the Textures subfolder) into the ImageTarget, only the .3ds file itself. Does anyone know how to apply the original textures to the car?

Thanks so much for your help in advance!
Ben

Comment: (I downloaded the 3d car object off this page: http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/ford-focus-28130.html)

Answer (score 1):

Well, to start answering your question about the drifting away part, you've probably got a `Rigidbody` attached to your Car? Well, if that's the case, then Go to the `Inspector` where the `Rigidbody` is and you'll see constraints.

To avoid it floating off, you might want to check `Freeze Positions` for whichever direction it needs. Probably `Y` axis.

Now, I'm not entirely sure if you're using Vector.AddForce to move your objects, but if you are then just check if your car can move if you've put all constraints on.

If you can't then in your code trying using `Object.Rigidbody.SetActive(true)` when you need it to start moving, and `Object.Rigidbody.SetActive(false)` when its done.

On the other hand, if you aren't using `Vector.AddForce()` then remove `Rigidbody` component if you've used it.

As for the material. If you've got the material in your folder that you've downloaded then just drag and drop it into `Assets`. Now sometimes your car may be one solid mesh, but some times it may be multiple meshes. So which ever the case. Drag the material from your `Assets` onto the `Hierarchy` panel over your car mesh/meshes and it should turn into that color.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks man! Much appreciated. Can't access my Unity file at the moment but I will try out these methods when I can. Really appreciate your in-depth / speedy response.